# jQuery Sizzle - Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

One of our projects was using jQuery sizzle but I am getting the following error message. This message appears on clicking a  tagged element in the navigation bar.

```
jquery-3.5.0.js:1677 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://localhost/myproject
    at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery-3.5.0.js:1677)
    at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery-3.5.0.js:2377)
    at Sizzle.select (jquery-3.5.0.js:2838)
    at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery-3.5.0.js:894)
    at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery-3.5.0.js:3095)
    at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-3.5.0.js:3205)
    at jQuery (jquery-3.5.0.js:157)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> ((index):925)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.5.0.js:5429)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.5.0.js:5233)
```

Here are my codes

**Layout Page (included in all pages)**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light static-top MONTSERRAT_LIGHT">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img class="text-left" src="{{ asset('images/thumbnail_image@1X.png') }}"/>
                    <!---<p class="site_subtitle">Your operation accelerated</p>-->
                </a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-lg-8" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link scroll_bottom" href="{{url('/')}}">About Us</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link scroll_bottom" href="{{url('/')}}">Content 1</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link"  href="{{url('content2')}}">Content 2</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link scroll_bottom" href="{{url('/')}}">Contact Us</a>
                      </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It looks like a selector is malformatted. We need to see the executed JS when "_a tagged element_" is clicked. Also, please fill the placeholders of the links in the markup with their real content.

Comment: @Teemu Can you let me know which js file is used? I am having a hard time finding it out

Comment: ?? Isn't that your own code? You're supposed to know where the clicks on the anchors are handled.

Comment: @Teemu No. I am supposed to correct the errors

Comment: @Teemu Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
 throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
};

Comment: How is that? It's trivial to find the event handlers with the DevTools. Just open the Inspector tab and click on a link. Depending on the browser, you can find which events are attached to the element (in FF there's an event icon in the markup, Chrome shows the events from the context menu).

Answer (score 1):

you update code to run on jQuery 3.0 or higher, once you have used Migrate 1.x and upgraded to jQuery 1.9 or higher:

Do the below steps in your project

Download the compressed, production jQuery Migrate 3.3.2

Download the uncompressed, development jQuery Migrate 3.3.2

It will resolve the issue.